# How do Aspect Miracles and Auctoritas interact?

Tags: powers, nobilis

In Nobilis does the Auctoritas defend against Aspect Miracles? What would this look like, i.e. how best to roleplay to avoid "forcefield" phenomena.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

For example, if a character use an Aspect Miracle to push someone across the world, unless they spend enough Miracle Points to overcome the targets Spirit, they would not be pushed.

Nobilis is not really meant to be a Noble on Noble game. If it comes down to a fight then normally all a character will do is create a future enemy and the problem will escalate. Remember Noble and Imperials rarely die only get more determined.

When I was refereeing a game a long time ago, it might have even been with LPB, I had a player which was a Inferno. He had annoyed another NPC Noble, so he create a trap where the Auctoritas disabled the miracle and hence a gigantic tree worm burrowed up from beneath him and attempting eat the player character. Where was then a great scene of the character jumping from almost total doom and running across the tree of life (IIRC).